# Replace empty value from colum by first word from another column's string

Tags: python, string, split, fillna, pandas-loc

I'm a beginner in Python.  I have a df named **df_opensports** with lot of columns. One column is named **'Sub_Categoria'**. Another Column is named **'Name'**. I need to fill empty values from 'Sub_Categoria' with the first word from the same 'Name' column index.  For example, if in idx 10 from df_opensports , the value from 'Sub_Categoria' is empty, then, fill it with the first word from the 'Name' string in the same index. I´ve seen many posts, and tried different ways, like this:

```
df_opensports.loc[df_opensports.Sub_Categoria == '', 'Sub_Categoria']=df_opensports.Name.str.split().str.get(0)
```

but the result for each empty value in 'Sub_Categoria' is still empty....What am I doing Wrong?

An example of de df :

[image: df]

for example, in the first line , instead of NaN, I need to get 'mocasines'

Thanks in advance

Comment: What form is the `Name` column? Can you show an example of this column?

Comment: Hi!, Amirhossein Kiani,Yes, of course!,  I've edited the post.

Comment: From what I see, you do not have `Sub_Categorias`, rather you have `Sub_Categoria`. Anyway, I am gonna answer your question based on the image of your dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the best idea, but I believe it would solve your problem:

```py
for index, row in df_opensports.iterrows():
  if row["Sub_Categoria"] == None:
    df_opensports.loc[index, "Sub_Categoria"] = row["Name"].split(" ")[0]
```

Thanks to your comment, I remembered another approach for this question:

```
df_opensports.Sub_Categoria.fillna(df_opensports.Name.apply(lambda x: x.split(" ")[0]), inplace=True)
```

Comment: thanks! but it´s not working...the Sub_Categoria values are still empty....

Comment: @MaximilianoVazquez my bad. I have edited the code. Check if it works for you or not.

Comment: No...it´s not working...I tried with 1) if row["Sub_Categoria"] is None: and it´s not working...
Then I tried with 2)  if row["Sub_Categoria"] ==' ': but it didn´t work.
3) df_opensports.Sub_Categoria.fillna(df_opensports.Name, inplace=True)  works, but I Get the complete string, I can't split it and get the first word because it seems to be a list

Comment: @MaximilianoVazquez In the third approach that you mentioned, I think you can use `df_opensports.Name.apply(lambda x: x.split(" ")[0])` as exactly as I mentioned in the edited version of my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! it worked! I was goging crazy!!! hehehehe